# Server-Client in java using TCP/IP.Cannot send/receive messages

Tags: java, networking, client-server, tcp

So I was making a simple chat application to get a kick-start in Java Networking.I am using TCP/IP.The problem is that the client does not send/receive data from the server, and neither does the server.Where am I doing it wrong?
Here is my server class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server implements Runnable {
static InetAddress address;
static ArrayList<Integer> clients=new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Socket> s=new ArrayList<Socket>();
static String message;
static byte[] mess=new byte[2048];
static DataOutputStream toClient;
public Server(InetAddress address){
    this.address=address;

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ServerSocket socket=new ServerSocket(8000);
    System.out.println("Server started on port 8000");

    while(true)
    {   
        Socket socketNew=socket.accept();
        s.add(socketNew);
        address=socketNew.getInetAddress();
        System.out.println("connected to client at address: "+address);
        InputStream is=socketNew.getInputStream(); //receiving from client
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        message=br.readLine();

        Server server=new Server(address);
        //new Thread(server).start();


    }
}


public void run() {

for(Socket socket:s) //to send message to all clients
{
    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(osw);
        bw.write(message);
        bw.flush();
        socket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}

}
```

And here are my client class' send and receive functions:

```
    private void send_data() {
    try {
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(osw);
        String sendMessage=this.getName()+": "+textField.getText();

        bw.write(sendMessage);
        bw.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}



private void receive_data()
{

    try {
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        String toConsole=br.readLine();

        console(toConsole);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but shouldn't you bind the ServerSocket to an IP, too? Try to use the ServerSocket constructor which gets an IP address, too.

Comment: You use bind with unbound ServerSocket. This one will not require that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did you wrote your client code to connect to the `Server`, and I don't know if you setup your `ip-configuratoin` right or wrong.

Typically there is little trick in writing something through `Socket` and `ServerSocket` and it is to add a line separator at the end of your message to enable the other side to `readLine()` from socket.

This can be achieved by appending `\n` to the message. But I myself prefer to use `PrintWriter` instead of `BufferedWriter`, because it has a set of elegant overloaded `println` methods which do this for you automatically:

```
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(bw);
p.println(message);
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is waiting to receive /n terminated message from the client.

Server Code:

```
package general;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChatServer implements Runnable {
static InetAddress address;
static ArrayList<Integer> clients=new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Socket> s=new ArrayList<Socket>();
static String message;
static byte[] mess=new byte[2048];
static DataOutputStream toClient;

public ChatServer(InetAddress address){
    this.address=address;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ServerSocket socket=new ServerSocket(9000);
    System.out.println("Server started on port 9000");

    while(true)
    {   
        Socket server=socket.accept();
        s.add(server);
        address=server.getInetAddress();
        System.out.println("connected to client at address: "+address);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
        String resp = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server received from Client:" + resp);
        server.close();

        /*
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socketNew.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(in.readUTF());
        DataOutputStream out =
                new DataOutputStream(socketNew.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to "
            + socketNew.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");
        */
    }
}


public void run() {

    for(Socket socket:s) //to send message to all clients
    {
        OutputStream os;
        try {
            os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(osw);
            bw.write(message);
            bw.flush();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

}
```

Client Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        client=new Socket("127.0.0.1",9000);
        System.out.println("connected to: " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
        String sendingMessage = "Hello Server - This is the client!\n";
        bw.write(sendingMessage);
        bw.flush();

        System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+ sendingMessage);

        /*
        OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

        out.writeUTF("Hello from \n" + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
        InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
        System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
        */
        client.close();         
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

Server:
    Server started on port 9000
    connected to client at address: /127.0.0.1
    Server received from Client:Hello Server - This is the client!

Client:
    connected to: /127.0.0.1:9000
    Message sent to the server : Hello Server - This is the client!